# Ruby loop issues

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I can't seem to get this loop working correctly

```
@mr = MediaRating.where("user_id = ?", session['user_credentials_id'])

unless @mr.empty?
  @mr.each do |rating|
    @m = Media.where("id = ?", rating.media_id)

    @m.each do |m|
      @history << m
    end
  end
end
```

In the MediaRating table there is only 3 test rows of data, but when I output the data on the screen the `@history` array contains 9 entries. I know it has to do with something I am doing wrong with the loop, but can't figure it out.

Working code

View:

```
<!-- For Each -->
<% unless @history.empty? %>
  <% @history.each do |m| %>
    <tr class="control_result_row">
      <td class="control_result"><%= m.first.title %></td>
      <td class="control_result">Russian</td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <tr class="control_result_row">
    <td class="control_result" colspan="2">You have no ratings logged</td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<!-- End For Each -->
```

Controller:

```
@mr = MediaRating.where("user_id = ?", session['user_credentials_id'])
@mr.each do |rating|
  @m = Media.where("id = ?", rating.media_id)
  @history << @m
end
```

Comment: What does Media contain? Check what @m contains after the nested Media.where call

Comment: re: your ERB with embedded `unless/else` logic. I prefer not seeing that combo in code when I'm doing code reviews or working on other people's code. I find that combo makes my brain downshift to figure out what is going on as I decipher the `not` implied in the `unless`. See John Nunemaker's ["Unless, The Abused Ruby Conditional"](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/) article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many things are in the `Media` table?  If that returns 3 things for each `MediaRating`, your loop is fine.

Also, `unless @mr.empty?` is not needed, because if `@mr` is empty, the `each` block will do nothing.

I think this is all you need:

```
@mr = MediaRating.where("user_id = ?", session['user_credentials_id'])
@mr.each do |rating|
    @m = Media.where("id = ?", rating.media_id)
    @history << @m
end
```

`@m = Media.where("id = ?", rating.media_id)` should only return one thing if `id` is a key.

Comment: There are 3 things in the MediaRating table (for testing purposes currently), but there are 100s of items in the Media table

Comment: what is `@history` supposed to contain? `Media` or `MediaRating`s

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip on the unless statement, still trying to learn ruby

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am adding in my working code above... it was an issue with me trying to pass an array into a :collection for a partial.. like I said still trying to learn Ruby/Rails :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding the wrong values to the @history array.
If you want the mediaRating history you should add media rating right.

```
@history << mr
```

or it looks like a data issue. Verify the foreign key dependencies.

Comment: Well I need to add the values from `@m` into the history array. I need to loop through each MediaRating to search the Medias DB

Comment: can you add a print in the second each and see how many time it executes that body. Add some data points which will also be helpful. Since there are 100's of media, check the size of @m before iterating. Can you change the variable name in the second each to something like |media| ??